# Firebase Deploy Not Updating/Hard Reload Not Working

Tags: firebase, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

My up-to-date files, specifically my JS file, are not reflected in the files deployed by Firebase on Chrome (I do not have this problem on Safari). I followed instructions [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192901/firebase-deploy-not-updating-js-file)

On Chrome, I went directly to [my file](https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com/app.js) and did a "Hard reload" and a "Empty Cache and Hard Reload", but the change was never reflected.

Essentially, Firebase is using this version of app.js:

```
    function.googleSignin(){
   var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  var email = error.email;
  var credential = error.credential;
});
```

But my local version is this:

```
    function googleSignin(){
   var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  var email = error.email;
  var credential = error.credential;
});
```

If you'd like to inspect my project, the GitHub link is [here](https://github.com/madelinezec/-Users-madelinezechar-columbiarideshare-pub/blob/master/app.js).

Comment: Hi Elizabeth. Please post the relevant details/code snippets over here instead of having the community go over to GitHub. It'd be faster for them to see the details. Cheers! :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now.  Did this just start working for you at some point?

Comment: @sonicblis - yes it did. I basically debugged my code by serving my app locally until I was finally ready to deploy (yesterday actually). Deploying yesterday was successful. It can still take a couple of hours for the changes to be reflected(safari is faster than chrome i've noticed), but it does eventually update