# Firebase ignores new functions during deployment and only deploys old ones?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a new function with `firebase deploy functions`, however it completely ignores any new code, and deploys functions that I have already deleted.

I am using typescript, so maybe firebase is not compatible with typescript and can't keep up with changes?

my package.json:

```
  "main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
```

I checked the lib/functions/src/index.js and I don't see any of my new typescript code, I just see the old functions, why are they there?

I thought that firebase deploy automatically turns typescript code into regular javascript, but turns out thats not the case.

Comment: Can you provide the full package.json file and the function code?

Comment: Meanwhile you can try the methods mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34193791) which may help.